# powershell get computer name where is script located when running from another computer

Tags: powershell, computer-name

I have script that is executable from another computer.

How to get comptername of location script? Just name, not full path (because the script can be distributed anywhere) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Solved on my own. :-) Hope that helps someone.

```psh
$scriptPath = Split-Path -Parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition
[string[]]$sth = $scriptPath.Split('\',[System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries)
$servername = $sth[0]
```

Comment: More PoSh: `$servername = ($scriptPath -replace '^\\\\' -split '\\')[0]`.